# localhost vs hostname, the hostname is not working properly

Tags: apache, localhost, cakephp-1.3, httpd.conf

I havev a cakePHP app (old 1.3x) which works (production). now I am trying to install wamp on my win7 - for dev purposes.
I am using "bitnami"'s wamp.

For that - i changed the `hosts` file added the `127.0.0.1   mydomain` row.
I also changed the `httpd.conf` file, adding the following:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName mydomain
  DocumentRoot "D:\wamp/apache2/htdocs/foldername"
  DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
</VirtualHost>
```

it's done.
Accessing `http://localhost/folder` works (some inner links problem, but it is expected - since it have some relative urls)

Accessing `http://mydomain` returns 200/ok response, but it is empty.

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: WSOD (White screen of Death). You have an underlying problem running your "index.php" Review the error logs to find out why they are giving you the white page. If you don't believe me, add a non-php file such as a give or a hello.txt with "hello world" in it, you will see it loads perfectly fine.

Comment: shame on me... it was a commented php line (the only one) in the index.php file.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like everything was fine. I simply commented the `require 'webroot' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'index.php';` line...
did it as a temp-test, and when i've `ctrl+z` the change, i left it unsaved.

it is fixed.
thanks